# What does "he is no loss!" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> “The moment that - that thing entered the room,” she screamed, pointing at Fudge, trembling all over, “it swooped down on Crouch and - and -”
>
> Harry felt a chill in his stomach as Professor McGonagall struggled to
>   find words to describe what had happened. He did not need her to
>   finish her sentence. He knew what the dementor must have done. It had
>   administered its fatal kiss to Barty Crouch. It had sucked his soul
>   out through his mouth. He was worse than dead.
>
> “By all accounts, **he is no loss!**” blustered Fudge. “It seems he has
>   been responsible for several deaths'.”
>
> “But he cannot now give testimony, Cornelius,” said Dumbledore.

I guess *he is no loss!* probably means *he is useless*. But I'm not sure if my understanding is correct. What does it mean exactly?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You're right. Literally it is saying "losing him is not a loss, i.e. not losing anything of value".

Comment: Yep I find Rowling's phrasing a bit weird here. I would not say "he is no loss" but rather talk about how the death was no loss. Maybe that's just me.

Comment: Maybe, @LightnessRacesinOrbit: it seems fine to me. In the British National Corpus, only one of the ten instances of "no great loss" is predicated of a person.

Comment: It's just [metonymic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metonymy), @Lightness.  In this context I take "he is no loss" to mean "his debilitation represents no loss".

Comment: @GaryBotnovcan I get what it means and how it's formed, it just doesn't seem like a common usage to me. But then of course my sample size is relatively low.